# Joins causing duplicate IDs

Tags: c#, linq

I've quite a complex query, essentially I have table a which in turn needs to get values from table b, table c and table d. I need to get the max value of something from table c and d so therefore I am grouping by the ID of table a. I also have left outer joins from table a to table b, c and d.

However the results returned are coming in like this.

```
id = 1 column x = 0000001
id = 2 column x = 0000001
id = 3 column x = 0000004
id = 3 column x = 0000005
id = 4 column x = 0000001
```

As you can see I wish to get the max from column x for id 3 instead of a value for both.

My query looks like this:

```
var q = from t1 in Table1.ToExpandable()
group t1 by t1.id into gt
join t2 in Table2 on gt.FirstOrDefault().FieldID1 equals t2.ID into gt2 from t2 in gt2.DefaultIfEmpty()
join t3 in Table3 on gt.FirstOrDefault().FieldID2 equals t3.ID into gt3 from t3 in gt3.DefaultIfEmpty()
join t4 in Table4 on gt.FirstOrDefault().FieldID3 equals t4.ID into gt4 from t4 in gt4.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new 
{
    Id = gt.FirstOrDefault().ID,
    T2FieldName = gt2.FirstOrDefault().T2FieldName,
    T3FieldName = gt.Max(x => gt3.FirstOrDefault().T3FieldName),
    T4FieldName = gt.Max(x => gt4.FirstOfDefault().T4FieldName)
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Seems like you need another level of group. Group over your `q` results.

Comment: What would be the most optimal way of doing that?

Comment: Creating a view in your database that does what you need (and calling it) is probably the most efficient way to do it..

Comment: About optimal way of doing it, see [is premature optimization really the root of all evil?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil)